# Theme: Twenty Fourteen, Carousel Slider categorywise below header image

Tags: theme-twenty-fourteen

I need to put a carousel slider below menu i.e. where the content goes in...
I need to have different carousel slider on different categories. Such as on books category carousel will relate to books, fashion it will relate to fashion products, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Install [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). Create a image upload field for the category referring to their docs. Use the following code in your archive.php

```
// get value from a taxonomy (taxonomy = "category", id = 1)
$image_cat = get_field('field_name', 'category_1');

<?php echo $image_cat; ?>
```